# is there a way to copy the entire $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to store all the contents of $scope to the local storage and load it back at a later time when the page reloads.
Is there a way to store all the contents of scope a variable?
Can I do something like this?

```
...
var vm = this;
...
localStorageService.set("allData",vm);
...
```

Comment: `this` has no relation to `$scope`.  It *almost* looks like you might be trying to use the ControllerAs syntax, with the `vm` variable; in that case, your `vm` is a property on `$scope`, not the `$scope` itself, but saving the vm to local storage isn't an issue....

Comment: I'm trying to save the entire $scope to local storage

Comment: What is the point of that?  This feels like an XY question.

Comment: Check out [`_.cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) if you are not using lodash.js already.

Comment: The "Angular way" is to use the [AngularJS Copy API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) which has a nice example of saving and restoring a `$scope`.

Comment: i am trying to save the state of a page and load it back to the same state

Comment: The state isn't necessarily defined by a single scope (most likely it isn't). It is your responsibility to store everything that is related to 'state' in single serializable object or a service that can aggregate it from other services. Most likely it has to be expressed with route/state params instead of just trying to dump everything.

Comment: `var copy = angular.copy(vm)` `localStorageService.set("allData",`copy);`  This will also copy functions on your scope... I would recommend to make objects of data that is usefull in your app page and only send this